# How to force PyPlot to show empty bins in a bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is a snippet of my code that plots bincounts:

```
pos = np.arange(len(ranger))
    print pos
    width = 1.0     # gives histogram aspect to the bar diagram

    ax = plt.axes()
    ax.set_xticks(pos + (width / 2))
    ax.set_xticklabels(ranger)

    plt.bar(pos, freq, width, color='b',)

    plt.savefig("binplotdisease/"+key+"_binplot.png")
    plt.close()
```

ranger is from 0,17. However, when I plot some data, I find that if, for instance, there is only one count for 9 and no other counts (the rest are 0), then only 9 shows up in the plot. For the purposes of my work, I'd like to be able to see the entire space from 0 to 17 so that I can better view trends. How can I change the plot settings so that empty bins are also seen?

Comment: could you rephrase your question properly. What do you mean by empty bins?? How can you show a bin first of all when it is empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `plt.xlim` explicitly to prevent matplotlib from automatically resizing the range of x-values displayed:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pos = np.arange(4)
freq = [0, 1, 3, 0]
width = 1.0     

plt.bar(pos, freq, width, color='b',)
plt.xlim(pos.min(), pos.max()+width)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is a known bug which has been fixed (can't find issue quickly....problem was 0 height patches were not taken in to account what computing the data lims).  The fix is on master branch and will be in 1.4